# Numerically solve multi-variables second-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, simulation

### Aim:

In order to simulate a circuit model, I need to numerically solve a equation set which contains multiple second-order ODEs.

### Equations of circuit:

The original equation set:
$$
\begin{align}
    \ddot \phi_1 & = \frac{1}{C_{J1}}\cdot(\frac{\phi_4-\phi_1-\Phi_{a1}}{L_1}-I_{c1}\sin\phi_1-\frac{\dot\phi_1}{R_{J1}})                             \\
    \ddot \phi_2 & = \frac{1}{C_{J2}}\cdot(\frac{\phi_4-\phi_2}{L_2}-I_{c2}\sin\phi_2-\frac{\dot\phi_2}{R_{J2}})                                       \\
    \ddot \phi_4 & = \frac{1}{C_{d1}}\cdot(\frac{\phi_5-\phi_4}{L_{d1}}-\frac{\phi_4-\phi_1-\Phi_{a1}}{L_1}-\frac{\phi_4-\phi_2}{L_2})                   \\
    0            & = \frac{\phi_9-\phi_6-\Phi_{a2}}{L_3}+\frac{\phi_9-\phi_7}{L_4}-\frac{\phi_5-\phi_4}{L_{d1}}                                          \\
    \ddot\phi_6 -\ddot\phi_5 &= \frac{1}{C_{J3}}\cdot\left[\frac{\phi_9-\phi_6-\Phi_{a2}}{L_3}-I_{c3}\sin(\phi_6-\phi_5)-\frac{\dot\phi_6-\dot\phi_5}{R_{J3}}\right] \\
    \ddot\phi_7 -\ddot\phi_5 &= \frac{1}{C_{J4}}\cdot\left[\frac{\phi_9-\phi_7}{L_4}-I_{c4}\sin(\phi_7-\phi_5)-\frac{\dot\phi_7-\dot\phi_5}{R_{J4}}\right]          \\
    0            & =\frac{\phi_9-\phi_6-\Phi_{a2}}{L_3}+\frac{\phi_9-\phi_7}{L_4}-i_b
\end{align}
$$
$I_x, R_x, C_x,L_x, i_b, \Phi_{x}$ are all known constant quantities. Only phase $\phi_n$ is a time dependent variable.  $\dot \phi_n$ and  $\ddot \phi_n$ are first-order and second-order time derivative of phase $\phi_n$.

The simplified equation set:
$$
\begin{align}
\ddot\phi_1 &= f(\phi_4, \dot\phi_1, \phi_1,t)\\
\ddot\phi_2 &= f(\phi_4, \dot\phi_2, \phi_2,t)\\
\ddot\phi_4 &= f(\phi_5, \phi_4, \phi_2, \phi_1,t)\\
0 &= f(\phi_9, \phi_7, \phi_6, \phi_5, \phi_4,t)\\
\ddot \phi_6-\ddot\phi_5 &= f(\phi_9-\phi_6,\dot\phi_6-\dot\phi_5, \phi_6-\phi_5,t)\\
\ddot \phi_7-\ddot\phi_5
&=f(\phi_9-\phi_7, \dot\phi_7-\dot\phi_5, \phi_7-\phi_5,t)\\
0 &= f(\phi_9,\phi_7, \phi_6,t)
\end{align}
$$
There are total 7 equations and 7 unknowns($\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_4, \phi_5, \phi_6, \phi_7, \phi_9$), so it must have a solution. I need to numerically solve these 7 equations simultaneously.

There are total 6 second-order items( $\ddot \phi_1,\ddot \phi_2,\ddot \phi_4,\ddot \phi_5,\ddot \phi_6,\ddot \phi_7 $ ), in order to numerically solve it, I need to set 12 initial values for them. The initial values are:
$$
\dot \phi_1=\dot \phi_2=\dot \phi_4=\dot \phi_5=\dot \phi_6=\dot \phi_7=0\\
 \phi_1= \phi_2= \phi_4= \phi_5= \phi_6= \phi_7=0
$$
ps: I am not sure if I set the initial conditions right or wrong, maybe I should set initial conditions for other items.

Notice that the LHS of the fifth and sixth equation is  ($\ddot \phi_6-\ddot\phi_5$) and  ($\ddot \phi_7-\ddot\phi_5$) ,  here comes the problem, I don't know how to numerically solve them. I can numerically solve the General second-order ODE, like
$$
\ddot y = f(\dot y, y, t)
$$
but I don't know how to solve my *multi-variables coupling* equation set, like ($\ddot \phi_6-\ddot\phi_5$) and ($\ddot \phi_7-\ddot\phi_5$) in it.

Could anyone teach me how to transform my equations, so I can then use some ODE solvers (like ode45 in matlab) to solve this circuit equations.

Regards,

Mengfei

Comment: This is a DAE system, so you would be best served using a DAE solver. To be safe you would also have to first compute the differentiation index.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to supplement the knowledge of DAE. @LutzLehmann

Comment: @Jason-Bourne you should put some index in your $f$ functions, as they are not all the same.

Comment: @Jason-Bourne Can you post the actual $f$ functions? Depending on that, you may be able to pull this off with a relatively simple finite difference scheme that yields a nonlinear system of equations.

Comment: @PierreCarre I have posted the original equations. Also, I'm using python, and I'm looking to see if [Gekko](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) can solve my equations. Could you give me some advices?

Comment: You can replace the linear equations with their second derivatives. This should give the vector of second derivatives as the solution of a regular linear system. As such you can then solve this with standard ODE solvers. This of course only works if the second derivatives of the input functions exist and are available.